# How to fix infinity redirect in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka-http, http-redirect

I am creating a web server that responds to a request from the client to `/file/filename.txt` and receives the file `filename.txt` from S3.
(`filename` can be change(ex:utf8.txt, blahblah.jpg))

This code is the routing part:

```
    val route =
        concat(
          path("file" / """[^\s]+""".r) { redirectPath =>
          redirect(redirectPath, StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect)
          },
          path("filename.txt") {
            complete(S3Service.fileDownload("filename.txt"))
          }
        )
```

The server runs as follows:

```
val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) 
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

`This webpage has a red-direct loop error` occurs in the Chrome browser
when a request is sent to `/file/filename.txt`

I tried to use `redirectToTrailingSlashIfMissing` to solve this problem but failed.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the redirect? You are redirecting to the same path so that is always going to cause a loop.

Comment: `redurectPath` value is `filename.txt`. I want to redirect from `file/filname.txt` to `filename.txt` I think these two urls are different. Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure about the contents of `redirectPath`? I suspect it includes the whole path not just the trailing part.

Comment: I fixed it with `"""([^\s]+)"""` and printed `redirectPath` and found that return `utf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txt`

Comment: @Tim I set redirect url to `down/"+redirectPath+"/"` and checked redirect path with fiddler
The result was strange. It Requested to `file/down/filename.txt` path.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to log the parameter in case of `/file/`?
I guess your regex miss parentheses. 
try `"""([^\s]+)"""`.
see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html#examples
the regex sample use parentheses to match.

Comment: I saw that Akka docs and fix regex to `"""([^\s]+)"""` but the same error appeared.
`redirectPath` returned `utf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txtutf8.txt`

Comment: By adding `/` to `redirectPath`, `/redirectPath` became an absolute path and the problem was solved.